# Java DB select specific column on specific row

Tags: mysql, sql, javadb

First post ever here :) looking franticly for help.

What I'm trying to do is to retrieve a specific image stored as blob in my database. I can't figure out why this query is not executing, I'm getting an exception as soon as I reach the executeQuery statement.

My table is:

Name        xcoordinate    ycoordinate     vista
firstscree   0               0               imag
secondscreen 0               1               img2
... etc.

```
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement stmnt = null;
Connection con = null;

String host = ...
String unm = ...
String pswrd = ...

BufferedImage imgt = null;
InputStream fis = null;
int xcoord;
int ycoord;
int newcoord;

 String SQLNorth = "select vista from location where xcoordinate = "+xcoord+" and ycoordinate = "+newcoord;
            newcoord = ycoord + 1;
            System.out.println("New coord x and y are" + xcoord + newcoord);

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, unm, pswrd);
            stmnt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            rs = stmnt.executeQuery(SQLNorth);
            rs.next();  
            fis = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
            imgt = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(fis);
        Image newImg = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(imgt, null);
        img_1.setImage(newImg);
```

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: problem is it doesn't catch any SQL exception the execution just stops, I have a println just before the rs = stmnt.executeQuery(SQLNorth); and that's the last line ...

Comment: So you don't know for sure that you're actually getting an exception? You could try adding a try/catch on Exception just to see if you're actually getting a runtime exception, but you should see something in the console/log depending on how you're running this.

Comment: ok here we go The column position '2' is out of range.  The number of columns for this ResultSet is '1'.

Comment: What line is that? I don't see any references to column "2" in what you've posted...

Comment: Added the try catch clause and that was the message I got which is after this line rs = stmnt.executeQuery(SQLNorth); (if i add prints around it the 1st one will print and the second one won't and I'll get the column position error, the error code I got when catching e.getErrorCode is 20000. I'm running a JavaFX application and trying to load an image from database, I'm totally new to DB.

Comment: You should update the posted code with the entire method/class and post the stack trace that you got from the error. I posted an answer based on what you've given so far, but I'm not entirely sure what's going on because you haven't posted enough info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it has something to do with the way you're building the query. Try using a prepared statement instead.

```
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement stmnt = null;
Connection con = null;

String host = ...
String unm = ...
String pswrd = ...

BufferedImage imgt = null;
InputStream fis = null;
int xcoord;
int ycoord;
int newcoord;

String SQLNorth = "select vista from location where xcoordinate = ? and ycoordinate = ?";

newcoord = ycoord + 1;
System.out.println("New coord x and y are" + xcoord + newcoord);

con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, unm, pswrd);

stmnt = con.prepareStatement(SQLNorth);
stmnt.setInt(1, xcoord);
stmnt.setInt(2, newcoord);

rs = stmnt.executeQuery(SQLNorth);
rs.next();  
fis = rs.getBinaryStream(1);
imgt = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(fis);
Image newImg = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(imgt, null);
img_1.setImage(newImg);
```

Comment: well it worked I think I had a syntax error in the SQL xcoordinate wasn't written correctly, thank you anyway :)

Comment: awesome! Prepared statements are usually considered best practice anyway and they add a little bit of protection against SQL injection in the case that user input is part of the query!